# SQL select top 10 for each year

Tags: sql-server

I have a fact database from which I want to make a trendline based on top 10 items based on sum quantity for each item per year. 
I've done the following, but it does for example select more than 10 entities for my year 2007:

```
select TOP 10 sum(Quantity) as Quantity,DIM_Time.Year, DIM_Item.Name as Name 

from Fact_Purchase
join DIM_Item on DIM_Item.BKey_ItemId = Fact_Purchase.DIM_Item
join DIM_Time on DIM_Time.ID = Fact_Purchase.DIM_Time_DeliveryDate
where Fact_Purchase.DIM_Company = 2 and DIM_Time.ID = FACT_Purchase.DIM_Time_DeliveryDate

Group by dim_item.Name, DIM_Time.Year
Order by Quantity DESC
```

How do I select top 10 items with the highest quantity through all my years, with only 10 top entities for each year?

As you can guess, the company is individual, and Is going to be a parameter in my report

Comment: Do you want the top 10 entities for each year, regardless of their overall sum? Or the top 10 entities across all years broken out by their sum in each year?

Comment: Oh yea, sorry. I tried my best explaining! 
- I want their respective sum for each year, to see how the quantity ordered for each year has developed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're going for. My apologies if I messed up on translating your tables across.

```
select *
from (
    select DIM_Time.[Year], dim_item.Name, SUM(Quantity) Quantity, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Time.[Year] ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC) salesrank
    from Fact_Purchase
        join DIM_Item on DIM_Item.BKey_ItemId = Fact_Purchase.DIM_Item
        join DIM_Time on DIM_Time.ID = Fact_Purchase.DIM_Time_DeliveryDate
    where Fact_Purchase.DIM_Company = 2 and DIM_Time.ID = FACT_Purchase.DIM_Time_DeliveryDate
    group by dim_item.Name, DIM_Time.[Year]
) tbl
where salesrank <= 10
order by [Year], salesrank
```

The subquery groups by name/year, and the RANK() OVER part sets up a sort of row index that increments by SUM(Quantity) and restarts for each Year. From there you just have to filter out anything with a salesrank (index) that's over 10.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    _year,
    Name,
    _SUM,
    RANK_iD
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                _year,
                Name,
                _SUM,
                DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY _year,_Month ORDER BY _SUM DESC) AS RANK_iD
            FROM(
                Select 
                    DIM_Time AS _year,
                    DIM_Item as Name,
                    sum(Quantity) AS _SUM
                from 
                    #ABC
                GROUP BY 
                    _year,
                    Name
             )A
         )B
    WHERE RANK_iD<=10
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are doing? It furthermore doesn't work.